# Need logic for UITableView's checkmark accessory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have 5 cells in my tableview.  User can select a row which sets the cells' accessory to check marked.  They can select multiple rows.

I want to make sure one cell is always check marked.  How can I do this?  All rows are check marked by default.

Here is the code I use in didSelectRow

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:iIndexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`. If there is only one element selected, return `nil` to indicate that the table may not deselect it.

Comment: I added new code above.  Based on the didSelectCode I have, how would I work with the deselect method?

Comment: `[[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRow] count] < 2`

Comment: I need to check if the cells are checked though, not if they are there.  THere will always be the same # of cells, the variable is whether or not the cells are checked.

Comment: Surely indexPathsForSelectedRow as obove will do this. It's not counting the rows, it's counting the selected rows.